# decode a data URL in php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I need to decode a data url in `PHP` .This data url is obtained via ajax.
I have used file reader to get the encoded data URL of an image.This data URL is passed to `PHP` via ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: app,
    async: false,
    type:"POST",
    data : "file="+strGlobalImageData,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    processData:false,
    jsonp: "jsoncallback",
    success: function(html){
        alert("Thank you. We will be in touch with you");
    },
    error: function(){
        alert("Thank you. We will be in touch with you");
    }
});
```

How will I do this?

Comment: can you add a string with the value of strGlobalImageData as it is received from the function?
Something like var_dump($_POST['file']);

Comment: What are you doing with the data after decoding it? PHP can access data:// using fopen or any other file handler. Or use base64_decode if you just have the encoded data.

Comment: check this please http://stackoverflow.com/a/18801110/953684

Comment: How are you encoding `strGlobalImageData`?

Comment: @Michael Dibbets.Its showing the encoded data<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'><small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjQKJeLjz9MKMyAwIG9ialsvSW5kZXhlZC9EZXZpY2VSR0IgMjU1KJSswURukmSGpHaUr0Fqj6O4yqO3yWKFo0tylbDC0X btLHC0qC1x4eiuISgt Do7aS5ylp nnKSrTxnjStag1J4mWWIpVd9nKm8zXmXsGmKp4mjuXCQq5 0x1N5mld8nNLc5V6BoNbf5zJfh3STrpuxxJKqv5KrwFV6m8bT3khwk6a5ylxcgJ8iUn3w9PcDOmsCOWoqWIIHPW0FPGxcYj5uBDtrSXGURm6SE0Z0OmaLPWiNH1F7OGSKXClZgTZi.....something like this

Comment: @Amit .(I am using file reader ) for (var i = 0, f; f = strFiles[i]; i++) { 
       
     var reader = new FileReader();
            // Closure to capture the file information.
            reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
               
                return function(e) {
                    // Render thumbnail.
                    strGlobalImageData=e.target.result;alert(strGlobalImageData);
                       
                };

            })(f);
          reader.readAsDataURL(f);
            
    }

Comment: @Anthony   Hi...I need to decode the data and I need name and tmp_name inorder to attach to an email

Comment: Sorry for anything wrong...but please help me...thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
$image =$_POST['file'] ;
```

Was this something you were looking for? Let me know

Comment: Yes.But this can be acheived with form submit method.Right?But I need to get it via ajax.

Comment: Yes. What you are actually trying to do ?

Comment: I need to attach a file with email in php.I want  ajax as carrier for the file as I explained above.What I did was I have read the data and encoded to 64 bit and sent to php.In php, how will I get this data.If we docode, we cannot get the file properties like tmp_name,name ....I think we need to write the data to a file ...Could you please say a suggestion

Comment: Here is a blog post  with a good example http://joekuan.wordpress.com/2009/06/12/ajax-a-simplified-version-of-file-upload-form-using-iframe/

And if you want to read filoename & other properties just add them as parameter in post.