# how to save image in the folder

Tags: php

Hi every on i write a code to save title and image name in the database but in my php code, i can save title text and image name in database but the image cannot be save in the folder(uploadedimages),

here is my code:

```
<?php
include 'config.php';

 $title = $_POST['title'];

  $base=$_REQUEST['image'];
$filename = $_REQUEST['filename'];
$binary=base64_decode($base);
header('Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8');
$file = fopen('uploadedimages/'.$filename, 'wb');
fwrite($file, $binary);
fclose($file);
mysql_query("insert into test_upload(title,img) values('$title','$filename' )");

 echo  "[".$title."]send";

?>
```

Comment: Change $base=$_REQUEST['image']; to $base=$_FILES['image'];

Comment: i change it but still can save image in the folder

Comment: Why you are converting image to base64 ?? You can directly move it from tmp location to your server?

Comment: Use this reference: [Click Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18801056/php-image-upload-function-save-in-a-dir-and-then-return-save-image-url)

Comment: Stop using the **deprecated and as of PHP7 removed** `mysql_*` functions. Migrate to PDO and start using Prepared Statements.

Comment: instead mysql Im using mysqli but its not working

Answer (score 0):

**Add the following code**

```
$filename = $_FILES['filename']['name'];


if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], 'uploadedimages/.'$filename)) 
{
echo "upload succeed";
} else {
 echo "Upload failed";
}
```